# Flatten and merge arrays and then split them back

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, flatten

Suppose that I have 3 matrces w2,w3 and w4 with shapes `(5,5)` `(5,5)` and `(5,1)`

Is there any efficient way to create a flatten array of those 3 matrices with shape `(55,1)` or `(55,)` (do some calculations) and then split this new array back to 3 matrices with the same shapes than the originals?

I have done this:

```
theta=w2.flatten()
theta=np.append(theta,w3)
theta=np.append(theta,w4)
```

and then:

```
w2=theta[0:25].reshape(5,5)
w3=theta[25:50].reshape(5,5)
w3=theta[50:].reshape(5,1)
```

but this seems to be slow. Is there any more efficient way?

Comment: Not sure what this is supposed to do but one thing to try is to concatenate all your arrays at once via `np.concatenate` or similar.

Comment: Could you provide some more insight in what you are calculating? Because the only way to speed up the first process is to pre allocate the space in `theta` and the later by writing the result directly in the original arrays with `w3[:] = theta[0:25].reshape(5, 5)`. But both of these actions wouldn't take a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

The function `flatten` performs a copy and `append` creates a new Numpy array while `reshape` does not.

You can use `np.concatenate` followed by `np.array_split` with some `reshape`. Here is how:

```py
# Flatten the matrices and concatenate the value in one new array.
theta = np.concatenate((w2.reshape(25), w3.reshape(25), w4.reshape(5)))

# Extract the 3 matrices and reshape them.
# Do not copy data, this just build 3 array views.
w2, w3, w4 = np.array_split(theta, [25, 50])
w2, w3, w4 = w2.reshape(5,5), w3.reshape(5,5), w4.reshape(5,1)
```